# Why does this JavaScript freeze IE6?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

When you click, "Add to Bag" on this page, it freezes IE6 every time. How can I figure out why it is freezing? Does anyone have a more direct answer?

totallytrollbeads {dot} com {slash} Safety0.html

```
function update() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/cgi-bin/ajax_cart_count.cgi',
        timeout: 2000,
        success: function (data) {
            // If bag is empty, it's see through.
            if (data.cart_count == 0) {
                $(".shopping_bag").css("opacity", ".2");
            }
            // If bag is not empty, it's not see through.
            else {
                $(".shopping_bag").css("opacity", "1");
            }
            $("#bag_total").html(data.grand_total);
            $("#bag_count").html(data.cart_count);
            window.setTimeout(update, 15000);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#bag_total").html('Timeout contacting server..');
            window.setTimeout(update, 60000);
        }
    })
}
$(document).ready(update);
```

---

```
// preparethe form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function () {
    // bind form using ajaxForm 
    $('.add_to_cart_form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: loading,
        success: myBox
    });
});
// preparethe form when the DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    // bind form using ajaxForm
    $('.add_to_cart_form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: loading,
        success: myBox
    });
});
// $(".add_to_cart_form").click(function () {
// $('.bypass_add_to_cart_form').ajaxForm({ success: myBox });
// });

function loading() {
    $("#loadingContent").show();
}
function myBox(resptext, statustext) {
    $("#loadingContent").hide();
    Boxy.ask(resptext, ["View Bag", "Continue Shopping"], function (val) {
        if (val == "View Bag") {
            document.location.href = "/cgi-bin/store.cgi?action=view_cart";
        }
        if (val == "Continue Shopping" && product_detail == 1) {
            history.go(-1);
        }
    }, {
        title: "Add to Bag"
    });
    $('.bypass_add_to_cart_form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: loading,
        success: myBox
    });
    update();
    return false;
}
/*     
 This tells the ajax-style add to cart that      
 it's on a product detail page so if the      
 user clicks "Continue Shopping" it takes      
 them back on step in their history.     
 */
$('.search_view').click(function () {
    product_detail = 0;
});
$('.product_view').click(function () {
    product_detail = 1;
});
```

Comment: Can you post your code for the Add to Bag button?

Comment: Borderline spam... I would suggest removing the link and posting the code that causes the behaviour you're referring to. If you don't have access to the code then why are you posting this question?

Comment: Sorry, here's the code for the add to bag button. I appreciate the feedback. Make sure you test the code in ie6.

Comment: @thealexbaron What does JSLint tell you?

Comment: Not sure what JSLint is... checking it out.

Comment: @thealexbron JSLint will tell you if your JavaScript code has bad parts.

Comment: @Šime Vidas JSLint is mostly telling me that I am calling functions before they are defined. Are these warnings that I should be concerned with?

Comment: @thealexbaron I am not sure. I think you should be fine. I would also love to know if this type of JSLint error is problematic.

Comment: @Šime Vidas I am picking out all of the errors that JSLint gives me, and I will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Whats wrong with this question, why do people keep voting it down?

Comment: @Roberto Sebestyen I don't know, I'm still trying to figure this one out. While JS Lint was a cool discovery for me, it didn't help much on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to debug a thing that freezes immediately from the outside. But it's always a good idea to cleanup the whole, remove things that are not essential, check the functionality and then do the next step.

For example this:

```
// preparethe form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function () {
    // bind form using ajaxForm 
    $('.add_to_cart_form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: loading,
        success: myBox
    });
});
// preparethe form when the DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    // bind form using ajaxForm
    $('.add_to_cart_form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: loading,
        success: myBox
    });
});
```

It's not hard to see that have this part twice there.
Put a little more accuracy into your application instead of copy&paste.